# playframework anorm postgresql timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql, playframework, anorm

Most web searches on this topic result in results which are years old.

Are there any updates to working with timestamps in Playframework / Anorm?

I have a postgesql column defined as...

```
timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
```

I'm looking for how to work with this column using Anorm. Links? Docs?

I am looking for the basics:

- what type do i use in my case class (scala)
- how to map to-from this type and the postgresql column without loss of time resolution

  ```
  case class VersionInfo(
    version: String,
    versionTimestamp: *// what type? joda-time? or java.util?*
  ){}
  ```

A sample or help doc page is what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is too broad. SO is for technical questions looking for technical answers. Do you have a specific problem that you can present?

Comment: I agree with @Patrick. It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to know how to convert such a date time object to a statement? Or the reverse, how to convert a row value to a date time? Is there a specific error? Could you post the code you're currently using or trying to use?

Comment: Basically, I want to map to-from the postgresql column to a case class parameter (lossless). In my tests with Slick this was simply to use org.joda.time.DateTime. I'd like to have more control over the SQL so I'm look at Anorm but I can't find doc on how to work with these database types.

Answer (score 0):

For now vanilla Java Date is supported with Postgresql TS, there is no JODA Time converter (but you can add an request for on Play github project).

Best